# Python - Normality score

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution

Having several DFs of events:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| Y | 0.5 |
| Y | 0.33 |
| Y | 0.5 |
| X | 0.33 |

Looking at the data of one DF I can see the following distribution for events Y,X

[image][image]

It is obvious that one distribution is **more** normal than the other. Trying to get a score for how normal the distribution is I've found [scipy.stats.normaltest](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html) but I'm not sure it is the right tool.

This is what I tried:

```
from scipy import stats

k2, p = stats.normaltest(data.event_X)
alpha = 1e-3
print("p = {:g}".format(p))
p = 8.4713e-19
if p < alpha:  # null hypothesis: x comes from a normal distribution
    print("The null hypothesis can be rejected")
else:
    print("The null hypothesis cannot be rejected")
```

---

**Q:** How can I automate the process, so for a given distribution I will get a score 0-1, how likely the distribution is normal?

Comment: Maybe you can use EMD (Earth mover's distance) https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html

Comment: Here is an article about it https://umfarooq0.medium.com/comparing-distributions-b7798b2e8e7e